# Insert attachment (post_meta) and combine it with post (email template)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I want to have a predefined email template with some attachments when the database is created.

I insert post_meta (email attachment) with post (email) using SQL but I don't get the expected result.

Biggest problem I have with creating `wp_postmeta.meta_value` is creating proper string, but with help of some online generator get it but still don't get result.

I'm trying to understand what I doing wrong.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` 
VALUES (1,1,'2022-06-26 01:00:00','2030-03-12 00:00:00','some text','','closed','','','','something','','','2022-06-26 00:00:00','2022-06-26 00:00:00','','','','','wcemailtemplates','','');

INSERT INTO `wp_posts` 
VALUES (2,1,'2022-06-26 01:00:00','2022-06-26 00:00:00','','someTitle','','inherit','open','closed','','test-test','','','2022-06-26 00:00:00','2022-06-26 00:00:00','','','/path/to/my/file.pdf','0','attachment','application/pdf','0');


INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` 
VALUES (87,2,'_wp_attached_file','fileName.pdf');

INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` 
VALUES (89,1,'wpcfu_file','a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";i:41;s:3:"url";s:84:"some/path/to/my/file.pdf";}}');

INSERT INTO `sk_postmeta` 
VALUES (90,37,'email_documents','');

INSERT INTO `sk_postmeta` 
VALUES (91,36,'_edit_last','2');
```

I hope I have clearly explained the issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to operate directly on the database yourself here - instead of using the functions WP provides to create posts, attachments & to set meta data?

Comment: I thought that this way they will automatically appear in the custom field. @CBroe